# Time Series Data Input for LSTM Model throws error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to use an LSTM model on time series data. The specific backgrounds of the data I'm working with is Twitter sentiment analysis for future price prediction. The data I have looks like this:

```
   date      mentions   likes  retweets  polarity  count   Volume   Close
2017-04-10     0.24     0.123    -0.58     0.211    0.58    0.98    0.87
2017-04-11    -0.56     0.532     0.77     0.231   -0.23    0.42    0.92
.
.
.
2019-01-10     0.23     0.356    -0.21    -0.682    0.23   -0.12   -0.23
```

Data is size (608, 8) and the features that I plan to use are columns 2 to 7, and the target that I'm predicting is `Close` (i.e. column 8). I'm aware that LSTM models require input to be in the shape of 3D tensors and so I made some operations to convert and reshape the data:

```
x = np.asarray(data.iloc[:, 1:8])
y = np.asarray(data.iloc[:. 8])

x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1])
```

Afterwards I attempted to train the LSTM model as such:

```
batch_size = 200
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(batch_size, input_dim=3, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15)
```

Running this model gives me a:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_10_input to have 
shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (1, 10)
```

Does anybody know where I went wrong? Is it in the way I prepared the data, or did I train the model wrong?

I've been reading many related questions on this community and also articles/blogs but I'm still having trouble finding a solution... Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Mistake 1:

The shape of x should be shape `(batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`

#### Mistake 2:

The first argument of LSTM is not the batch size but the output size

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,9))

x_train = df.iloc[:,1:8].values
y_train = df.iloc[:,8].values

# No:of sample, times_steps, input_size (1 in your case)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1], 1)

model = Sequential()
# 16 outputs of first LSTM per time step
model.add(LSTM(16, input_dim=1, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=15, batch_size=32)
```